# Why was this question about Luke Skywalker looking at a gravestone deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

This question: [Is Luke Skywalker looking at a gravestone and whose is it? [closed]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/128288/is-luke-skywalker-looking-at-a-gravestone-and-whose-is-it) was deleted 9 hours ago. Why?

Comment: Hmm. I wonder if the question should be undeleted and closed as a duplicate of [this one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/113995/31394) ... I *think* both are asking about the same stone, and the other question has been answered.

Comment: Are you worried that they made a ... grave mistake?

Comment: @Valorum I actually chuckled, sounded like a bloody madman at work. HAHAHA

Answer (score 8):

As is clearly explained on the banner beneath the question:

> deleted by Community♦ 9 hours ago (RemoveAbandonedClosed)
>
> This question was automatically deleted. [Please see the help center for more information.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/roomba)

Following that link:

> The Community user will automatically delete old abandoned/dead questions in the following circumstances:
>
> **If the question was closed more than 9 days ago, and ...**
>
> - not closed as a duplicate
> - has a score of 0 or less
> - is not locked
> - has no answers with a score > 0
> - has no accepted answer
> - has no pending reopen votes
> - has not been edited in the past 9 days

Answer (score 7):

Look at the deletion banner:

> **deleted** by Community♦ 9 hours ago (RemoveAbandonedClosed)
>
> This question was automatically deleted. [Please see the help center for more information.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/roomba)

Following that link leads you to the help centre page on automatic deletion. The section relevant to your specific question is:

> **If the question was closed more than `9` days ago, and ...**
>
> - not closed as a duplicate
> - has a score of 0 or less
> - is not locked
> - has no answers with a score > 0
> - has no accepted answer
> - has no pending reopen votes
> - has not been edited in the past `9` days
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted. These are "abandoned closed", and are termed as `RemoveAbandonedClosed`.

As a 10k-reputation user, you can vote to undelete this question. I don't think you can undelete it singlehandedly as the OP, however.

---

**EDIT:** your question has now been undeleted by three 10k+ reputation users. I also reopened it and closed it as a dupe of [What is the significance of this hand-shaped rock formation?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/113995/31394), a question asking about exactly the same stone which already has two good answers. I'm not sure why your question was originally closed as opinion-based and the other one wasn't.

Comment: Awesome, questions I want deleted won't be. But ones I don't want deleted will be...

Comment: @KyloRen It's now been undeleted, and marked as a duplicate instead of primarily opinion-based. Sometimes asking on meta does work :-)